# I can't get this code to work. Finds a file then filters and copies from another workbook and pastes into the sheet I'm working on

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Sub Get_Data()
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim openbook As Workbook
    
    ChDrive "O"
    ChDir "O:\AIRCRAFT\GREEN-COMPLETIONS\Special mission\2. Work In Progress\Q400 - Conair\SN 4631 AC 5\Planning"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for you are file", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*),*xls*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Set openbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$20").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=RGB(0, 112 _
        , 192), Operator:=xlFilterFontColor


    openbook.Sheets(2).Range("a1:e20").Copy


    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    openbook.Close False
     
     
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
   Range("AA5").End(xlDown).Select
       
End Sub
```

I can't tell what I'm doing wrong. I'm getting a two cells of data pasted into my book. The data coming from the first sheet, not the second like I specified.

Comment: Why are you using `ActiveSheet`?

Comment: I was trying to use openbook.range, but the object doesn't support the property.

Comment: openbook.sheets("name_here").range() is the correct syntax

Comment: Or `openbook.Sheets(2)` as you have right afterwards.